# Python debugger pdb not found on macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, debugging, macos-high-sierra

The [PythonDebuggingTools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools) documentation says that the Python debugger [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) is "part of all Python installations", yet I can't find it under macOS High Sierra:

```
pdb: command not found
```

Is it supposed to be installed as normal part of macOS these days?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is not a command named `pdb`, but you could invoke pdb from shell with:

```
python -m pdb your_script.py
```

you could read more methods to invoke `pdb` in [its doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you use IPython the debugger can be invoked by using

```
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %pdb
Automatic pdb calling has been turned ON

In [2]: %pdb
Automatic pdb calling has been turned OFF

In [3]: ?pdb
Docstring:
Control the automatic calling of the pdb interactive debugger.

Call as '%pdb on', '%pdb 1', '%pdb off' or '%pdb 0'. If called without
argument it works as a toggle.

When an exception is triggered, IPython can optionally call the
interactive pdb debugger after the traceback printout. %pdb toggles
this feature on and off.

The initial state of this feature is set in your configuration
file (the option is ``InteractiveShell.pdb``).

If you want to just activate the debugger AFTER an exception has fired,
without having to type '%pdb on' and rerunning your code, you can use
the %debug magic.
File:      ~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py
```

You may need to install IPython with either pip or conda.